# Utility to print a separator onto screen

Tags: shell, terminal

Often when I'm working on a terminal I'll print out config files using cat to read them. After my terminal becomes full and I'm scrolling back it becomes hard to distinguish various blocks of text.

It would be useful if one could insert a colored line by running a command to serve as a demarcator. This could be as simple as writing a shell function that loops and prints `_`.

However, I'm wondering if there is already a utility out there that does this. It would be better than something I would write myself, and deal with different terminal widths, use colors that are available etc.

Comment: Sounds like you'd want to include that coloured line as part of your shell prompt. See for instance [How to set HOSTNAME in zsh?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/209463) here for the zsh shell as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This alias sets one row on the terminal to a new background colour.

```
alias vv='tput setab 3; printf "%*s" $( tput cols ) ""; tput setab 0; echo'
```

The colours from `man terminfo`:

```
Color     Value
black       0
red         1
green       2
yellow      3
blue        4
magenta     5
cyan        6
white       7
```

The standard command `tput` outputs terminal controls characters for the specific terminal type exported in `TERM`, so it should be portable. The `setab` and `setaf` options affect the background and foreground colours, which are supplied as numeric values.

The `tput cols` is a query, whose return is used here to make the `printf` output exactly one row of blanks, which are rendered with the temporary background colour.

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't seem to work on Cygwin or on Bash (CentOS). Also, do you mind including a little explanation of how tput, setb work?

Comment: By not work I mean, there's just a blank line with no color change.

Comment: The answer should use `setaf` and `setab` rather than `setf` and `setb` (read the manpage more carefully).

Comment: @KshitizSharma I tested with a full screen, where the shell racks up the row and it gets repainted. Before the screen is full, nothing new gets drawn. Fixed that by blanking the line explicitly. Explained where to find documentation on the commands, and used the more portable setab option as per Thomas (although both versions worked for me).

Comment: Great answer! Thanks.